# Safecracker Registration: changing email address?

Tags: members, safecracker-registration, member-details

I'm using Safecracker Registration and was able to create a form with an `email` field. When a new email address is entered in it and the form is submitted, the Member's email is actually updated.

Is there a way to make EE not just instantly update the email, though? Shouldn't it first verify that the email is valid by sending an email with an activation link? That's how I have things set up for initial sign ups.

I don't think this is specifically a Safecracker Registration issue, but rather an EE one. However, I can't seem to find a "Members must verify email change" option in the CP. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a limitation of the EE member module. Safecracker Registration works by converting the existing Member module to use Safecracker and channel entries, but it's all the Member module under the hood.

That is a good feature request and something I would have to implement on my own, since it's not supported by first-party libraries.

Comment: Thanks Justin. It seems silly that EE is able to validate an email address on sign up, but when the email is changed later on, it doesn't bother to do that anymore. Oh well.